# Inserting data from a list of object to an array on C#

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, list

I have a list from an object. The object is representing a point where a line og parked cars located on a location and the direction the cars are pointing at. The object contains several types of data which also acts as attributes. There are 4 of them in the list. Here's the types and the variable name of them.

```
public enum Direction
{
    North,
    West,
    South,
    East
};

public class Location
{
    public Int16 X {set; get;}
    public Int16 Y {set; get;}
    public Direction Z {set; get;}
}
```

What I'm trying to do is a testing whether my program runs well or not. And I'm intended to test it by putting all the 'X' in an array and display them on a console window. I'm using a WPF and a background thread processing to do all the stuff. Any idea or suggestion on how I do it? I've been trying several ways like To.Array() from Linq but it always comes out that the new array I use to contain the data is null.

Comment: The question is no 100% clear to me. Do you want to make an Object and Store them to an Array then try to iterate them?

Comment: @Aizen I'm trying to make an array from one of the attributes in the object. I would like to gather all the 'X' to an array and display it in a console window for a testing purpose. By now I'm still trying all the answers given below.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want List or ArrayList etc etc. So I provided the most simpliest Linq. Make sure to add using System.Collections.Generic;

```
class Program
{
    public enum Direction { North, East, South, West };
    static List<Location> myObjects = new List<Location>();


    public class Location
    {
        public Int16 X { get; set; }
        public Int16 Y { get; set; }
        public Direction  Z { get; set; }

        public Location(Int16 x, Int16 y, Direction z)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Z = z;

        }

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myObjects.Add(new Location(10, 10, Direction.North));
        myObjects.Add(new Location(30, 20, Direction.East));
        myObjects.Add(new Location(50, 5, Direction.West));
        myObjects.Add(new Location(60, 32, Direction.South));

        foreach (Location it in myObjects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parked Location is {0}, X is {1}, Y is {2}", it.Z, it.X, it.Y);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to gather all the X points you could use:

```
 List<Location> allLocations = ...;

 var allX = from loc in allLocations select loc.X;
 foreach(int i in allX) 
 {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
 }
 var asAnArray = allX.ToArray();
```

---

Full Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum Direction
        {
            North,
            West,
            South,
            East
        };

        public class Location
        {
            public Int16 X { set; get; }
            public Int16 Y { set; get; }
            public Direction Z { set; get; }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            List<Location> allLocations = new List<Location> {
                new Location() {X=1, Y=2, Z = Direction.North },
                new Location() {X=2, Y=3, Z = Direction.West },
                new Location() {X=3, Y=4, Z = Direction.East }
            };
            var allX = from loc in allLocations select loc.X;
            foreach (int i in allX)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            var asAnArray = allX.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("Array is:" + (asAnArray == null ? "Null" : asAnArray.Length.ToString()));
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Or using a different syntax for the same effect.
            asAnArray = allLocations
                .Select(loc => loc.X)
                .ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("Array is:" + (asAnArray == null ? "Null" : asAnArray.Length.ToString()));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does from clause usable from Icollection? haven't tested t yet. Seems the fastest way to use linq.

Comment: @Aizen, if I understand your question correctly, yes-ish. WIth the `Using System.Linq` statement you get extension methods applied to IEnumerable and IQuerable, ICollection implements IEnumerable. The `from` keyword is c# syntactic sugar for calling the Select extension method on IEnumerable. ish.

Comment: var mySpecialPick = from test in myButtons where test.ButtonNumber == 4 select test;
            MyButtons myPick = myButtons.Find(w => w.ButtonNumber == 4);

I tried 2 different ways. The usual Linq to test in Generic List<T> is no doubt to work. Trying it with the from clause returns System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIteretor etc etc as the String. It does work perfectly in an Array though. I am going to try it now with ArrayList I am guessing it would work cause ArrayList lists implicit data types. Thanks David.

Comment: @DavidWaters I'm trying to use your answer. One thing I still don't understand is the asAnArray was null after all the process.

Comment: @undip_student Was your list empty? I have updated with full code which runs and produces an array at the end.

Comment: @DavidWaters yes, turns out it was empty by my mistake. I need to fix the method which caused the list to be empty. thanks for the answers everyone